# How could I resolve A generic error occurred in GDI+. in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, picturebox, memorystream

When image field property in class is set with the image raw format of the same image from my database in picture box, it always throws this exception. In contrast, if the image in the picture box has been updated with one I select from my local PC directory, the update function work fine.

Below is my code:

```
Try
   With mEmployee
     If Miscellaneous.GetImageName(ofdPhoto).ToLower = "No_Photo.jpg".ToLower Then
        .Image = Nothing
     Else
         Dim stream As New MemoryStream
         pbImage.Image.Save(stream, pbImage.Image.RawFormat)
         .Image = stream.GetBuffer()
     End If
  End With
Catch ex As Exception
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: You'll surely have to assume that the data in the dbase is not a properly encoded image that uses one of the standard file formats.  Not unusual for images stored in an Access dbase for example.  The code snippet does not appear relevant, it doesn't do anything with a dbase.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. This code is related to data setter for updating the database table with the line mEmployee.Image = stream.GetBuffer(). But at this point, it throws me an exception every time I don't choose a new picture to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now everything has solved. This GDI+ generic error caused by the picture box itself. Actually, When I bound the record with image from the database and update that record without updating the image in the PictureBox, the image field has been set with old byte() data from the box, and that caused the error.

To solve this, I have declare a byte() type variable to store the temp image byte() data from the database, and when update, if the image has not been changed it will be set with the data from that variable.
This is my code that solve everything:

```
Try
            If Miscellaneous.GetImageName(ofdPhoto).ToLower = "No_Photo.jpg".ToLower Then
                .Image = Nothing
            Else
                If isImageChanged = True Then
                    Dim stream As New MemoryStream
                    pbImage.Image.Save(stream, pbImage.Image.RawFormat)
                    .Image = stream.GetBuffer()
                    isImageChanged = False
                ElseIf isRemoveImage = True Then
                    .Image = Nothing
                    isRemoveImage = False
                Else
                    .Image = tempImage
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
```